# Is it possible to force schema definition when loading tables from AWS RDS (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Apache Spark to read data from **MySQL** database from **AWS RDS**.

It is actually inferring the schema from the database as well. Unfortunately, one of the table's columns is of type `TINYINT(1)` (column name : active). The `active` column has the following values:

- non active
- active
- pending
- etc.

Spark recognizes `TINYINT(1)` as **BooleanType**. So he change all value in `active` to `true` or `false`. As a result, I can’t identify the value.

**Is it possible to force schema definition when loading tables to spark?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not **spark** that *converts* the `TINYINT` type into a `boolean` but the j-connector used under the hood.

So, actually you don't need to specify a schema for that issue. Because what's actually causing this is the jdbc driver that treats the datatype `TINYINT(1)` as the `BIT` type (because the server silently converts `BIT` -> `TINYINT(1)` when creating tables).

You can check all the tips and gotchas of the jdbc connector in the MySQL [official Connector/J Configuration Properties guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

You just need to pass the right parameters for your jdbc connector by adding the following to your url connection :

```scala
val newUrl = s"$oldUrl&tinyInt1isBit=false"

val data = spark.read.format("jdbc")
  .option("url", newUrl)
  // your other jdbc options
  .load
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a schema, and use it when you read using

```
spark.read.schema(Schema)
```

[Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema)

**Example how to define a schema:**

```
// The schema is encoded in a string
val schemaString = "name age"

// Generate the schema based on the string of schema
val fields = schemaString.split(" ")
  .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
val schema = StructType(fields)
```

Now you can read the data using the predefined schema:

```
spark.read.schema(schema).function_to_read_data
```